# Seemingly Obvious Improper Integral Property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

The following seems extremely obvious, so much so that I cannot see how to prove it:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable then
>   $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{c\to b^-}\int_a^cf(x)dx$$

Comment: I think you have a typo in the left integral bounds (low bound should be $a$).

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to be Riemann integrable? Can you use that to show that the limit exists and that it equals the integral on the left?

Comment: Although not necessary, it's quite relevant and interesting (I hope!) to note that this result has a kind of converse, which equally "seems extremely obvious" (so much so that I glossed over it at first sight). Suppose that $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, and that the improper Riemann integral $\int_a^{b-} f = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_a^{b - \epsilon} f$ exists. Then the proper Riemann integral $\int_a^b f$ also exists, and is equal to $\int_a^{b-} f$. See e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311395) (but please ignore the last part of my confusingly-written answer).

Comment: The result you mention is not obvious, but at the same time not too difficult. If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ then $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. The result you mention is dealing with continuity of $F(x)$ at point $x = b$.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: thanks for the link to your answer which deals with the converse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the definition. Let $\epsilon > 0$. We want $\delta > 0$ such that if $b-\delta < x < b$, then $$\left|\int_a^bf(t)\,{\rm d}t-\int_a^xf(t)\,{\rm d}t\right| <\epsilon.$$Since $f$ is Riemann-integrable, $f$ is bounded almost everywhere by a positive constant, say, $M>0$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon/M > 0$ and note that: $$\left|\int_a^bf(t)\,{\rm d}t-\int_a^xf(t)\,{\rm d}t\right| = \left|\int_x^bf(t)\,{\rm d}t\right|\leq \int_x^b|f(t)|\,{\rm d}t\leq M(b-x) < M\delta = M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Yes, just like mine!  ;-))

Comment: Just a technical observation: a Riemann-integrable function is bounded *everywhere*.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it is bounded on $[a,b]$.  Let $M=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|=M$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{b-\delta}^{b}f(x)\,dx\right|&\le \int_{b-\delta}^{b}|f(x)|\,dx\\\\
&\le M\,\delta\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\delta<\epsilon/M$.

Comment: When I read the answers I couldn't tell which was written first; the time stamps all read the same number of hours and Ivo's answer was at the top. I chose Ivo's answer solely because it went into more detail and followed more closely the format of a limit proof that I'm used to. As a beginner, this made it slightly easier for me to understand. I did, however, upvote your answer because it helped me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Joey, thank you.  Much appreciative of your replying. -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Let $m$ and $M$ be lower and upper bounds for $f$ on $[a,b]$. Then the inequality
$$m(b-c)\leq\int_c^b f(x) dx \leq M(b-c)$$
is valid for all $c \in [a,b]$, which
implies that
$$\lim_{c \to b^-} \int_c^b f(x) dx = 0$$
Consequently,
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{c\to b^-} \int_a^c f(x) dx &= \int_a^b f(x) dx - \lim_{c \to b^-} \int_c^b f(x) dx \\
&= \int_a^b f(x) dx
\end{aligned}$$