# Explicit example that shows the difference between two definitions of the Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Given a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ it could make sense, depending on the situation, to define the integral of $f$ in either of the following ways:

1. Standard Riemann integral, assuming it exists.
2. Limit as $\varepsilon\to 0$ of the Riemann integral over $[a+\varepsilon, b]$, assuming the latter integral exists for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$.

Does anyone know an example of a function $f$ for which these two do not coincide? For instance a function for which the second method is well-defined but the Riemann integral does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)= n$ for $x=1/n$ for $n$ a natural number and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

For any $\varepsilon > 0$ on the interval $[\varepsilon, 1]$ this function is **bounded** and zero up to **finitely** many points. Hence the Riemann integral exists and is zero. So using definition 2. the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ exists and is equal to $0$.

However, on the interval $[0,1]$ this function has **infinitely** many discontinuities, is **unbounded** and is not Riemann integrable according to definition 1.

Comment: On the other hand, if $f$ is bounded, then 1 and 2 are the same. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311395, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1301170.

Comment: The failure of Riemann integrability (your last paragraph) is not due to infinite number of discontinuities, but more due to the fact that Riemann integration applies only to bounded functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The wording was misleading, I adjusted it.